# Make tests use a simulated version of the app engine "High Replication Datastore"?

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine, testing

According to App Engine website we should add this to our test:

```
LocalServiceTestHelper datastoreHelper = 
        new LocalServiceTestHelper( new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig( )
                                    .setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(100));
```

But running the test it prints this in the console:

```
INFO: Local Datastore initialized: 
Type: Master/Slave
Storage: /Users/celsodantas/code/eclipse-workspace/code/BAM/product/./WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin
```

My question is: **How do I make the test run against a simulated High Replication Datastore?**

All my tests was running using the Master/Slave before the App Engine migrate to HRD. My production app is already running the HRD but not my tests.

Any ideas? Tnx

Comment: It should work. I assume you have another LocalServiceTestHelper instance somewhere. Can you check the test source?

Comment: @TakashiMatsuo You're correct. We are also instantiating a MemCache test helper in the same test. In the setup, we call: datastoreHelper.setup, then memcacheHelper.setup and it fails. Reverse the order of the two and it works.

Comment: Okay let's make this an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Updated with an example]**
It should work. I assume you have another LocalServiceTestHelper instance somewhere. The constructor of `LocalServiceTestHelper` can receive multiple TestConfigs, so if you want to have multiple test configs, please try something like following:

```
private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(
 new LocalMemcacheTestConfig(),
 new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig()
   .setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(100));
```

Comment: So you aren't allowed to have multiple LocalServiceTestHelpers in the same test?

Comment: yes, indeed I have. I'm also instantiating a memcacheHlper.setup. So I'm not able to have more then 1 LocalServiceTestHelper in the app?